# Set default day and month following the current one, in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, date

I am using PHP+POSTGRESQL to insert into a table records whose date must be predetermined, in this case I must insert the date whose day is '5' always and the month, is the next one to the month in which the record was inserted. If I do an insertion today the date column should contain:

2017-04-05 (the format is YYYY-MM-DD)

For the month I had planned to add 30 days to the current date like this:
Now () + cast ('1 day' as interval) * 30, but there are months that do not have 30 days, so you could have problems. For the day, I do not know if there is a function to set the day of a date in Postgres so maybe there is a solution from the server side.

Any solution from the server or the database will be grateful.

Comment: `For the month I had planned to add 30 days ` - Why not to add directly 1 month ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sysdate::date as current, 
    (date_trunc('month', sysdate)+'1 month'::interval+'4 day'::interval)::date as next;

 current      | next
--------------+------------
 2017-03-23   | 2017-04-05
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I chose works correctly. For those looking for another solution with PHP, I have done this:

```
$mydate = date('Y-m-05');//Set the default day in this line
$fecha = date('Y-m-05', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($fecha)));//the next month
```